# Table is flushed to next page despite ample room on current page

Tags: tables, page-breaking

I tried inserting a table below some text. The issue is, it seemed to have shifted the table to the next page although there is ample room for it to fit in the page with text.  This is what I inputted:

```
%there is text up here%

\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Liposomal products on various markets around the globe, adapted from (15)} 

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c |}
\hline
\textbf{Product} & \textbf{Use} & \textbf{Market} \\
[0.5ex]
\hline

Doxil/Doxorubicin & cancer chemotherpay & USA/EU\\

DuanoXome & HIV-related Kaposi's Sarcoma & USA/EU\\

5-Fluorouracil & topical anticancer cream & Germany\\

Epaxel & hepatitis-A vaccine & Switzerland\\

Newcastle vaccine & newcastle disease vaccine for chickens & Global\\

Avian & rheovirus vaccine & Global\\

ELA-max & liposomal lipocaine & USA\\
\hline


\end{tabular}

\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Environment `center` adds additional vertical space, use `\centering` at the start of the `table` to avoid this. Please, complete the snippet to a full minimal example, so that the problem can be reproduced.